# c++ GetSystemTime returns 0 when debugging but returns correct output when stepping through breakpoint

Tags: c++, time

Im trying to get the time it takes for some functions to run but when I run using the debugger, I get zero. When I insert a breakpoint and step through the program, I get the correct output. Here is the code below.

```
vector<int> nums = { 5, 8, 1, 3, 9, 45, 12, 4 };
SYSTEMTIME startTime;
SYSTEMTIME endTime;
Sorter<int> s;
s.setData(nums);
GetSystemTime(&startTime);
s.bubbleSort();
s.combSort();
s.insertionSort();
GetSystemTime(&endTime);
auto diff = endTime.wMilliseconds - startTime.wMilliseconds;
cout << "Took " << diff << endl;
```

Comment: I bet even bogosort would work in less than 1ms on modern hardware for an array of 8 elements.

Comment: The initial data array to be sorted is too small to get valuable performance stats.

Comment: I used an array of 10000 numbers and its still returning zero. I just cant believe that bubble sort is sorting 10k random numbers in less than 1ms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should calculate the time difference:

```
_int64 Delta(SYSTEMTIME st1, SYSTEMTIME st2) 
{
  union timeunion 
  {
      FILETIME fileTime;
      ULARGE_INTEGER ul;
  };

  timeunion ft1;
  timeunion ft2;

  SystemTimeToFileTime(&st1, &ft1.fileTime);
  SystemTimeToFileTime(&st2, &ft2.fileTime);

  return ft2.ul.QuadPart - ft1.ul.QuadPart;
}
```